What sort of knowing does "we know" refer to in Romans 6:9?
Romans 6:9  ESV

"We know that Christ, being raised from the dead, will never die again; death no longer has dominion over him."  [My emphasis].

Here "we know" is eidotes.
Acts 1:3

"He presented himself alive to them after his suffering by many proofs, appearing to them during forty days and speaking about the kingdom of God."

In Ro 6:9 do the "we know" people know because they saw the physically resurrected Jesus?
1  Corinthians 15:3

"For I delivered to you as of first importance what I also received: that Christ died for our sins in accordance with the Scriptures."

In Ro 6:9 does  "we know" refer  to those who believed the report of others?
From Romans 6:6

"We know that our old self was crucified with him in order that the body of sin might be brought to nothing,...".

In Ro 6:6  "knowing" is not eidotes but ginoskontes. Suggesting to me another sort of knowing.
What sort of knowing does "we know" refer to in Ro 6:9?

This is where the preceding verses give the clue. In chapter 6, Paul writes to the Christians in Rome that they are now dead to sin. Given that fact, he expresses surprise that some might think they can continue to sin. "Know ye not..." he says in verse 3 that (likewise) they were baptized into his death? He adds:

"Therefore we are buried with him by baptism into death; that like as
Christ was raised up from the dead by the glory of the Father, even so
we also should walk in newness of life. For if we have been planted
together in the likeness of his death, that we shall be also in the
likeness of his resurrection." Romans 6:4-5 A.V.

Paul is explaining the theological significance of Christ's death and resurrection, for individual Christians. Many Christians had, indeed, witnesses the resurrected Christ with their own eyes, so in that sense they would 'know' experientially. They were eye-witnesses. Jesus commissioned them to be his witnesses (Acts 1:8), and those ones also witnessed his bodily ascension up into the clouds, being told by two men in white to stop gazing up, for Christ would return in like manner. They witnessed to that as well. Thousands soon believed their testimony. Their 'knowing' was different, as they knew due to multiple eye-witness testimony.
But every Christian who puts faith in the good news about Christ then comes to 'know' the truth of it in a different way. It is confirmed to them by the indwelling Holy Spirit. Christ becomes personally real to them as the living, resurrected Saviour and Lord they now put total faith in. Those, then, are the two ways of knowing that the New Testament speaks of.
But in verse 6, Paul reverts back to 'knowing' the doctrinal truth of what Christ's crucifixion and resurrection means for individual Christians. He explains the consequences of such saving faith having caused them to be "crucified with Christ" and "risen" with him. Therefore verse 8 speaks of knowing what will yet happen to them when the time comes for their bodies to be resurrected:

"Now if we be dead with Christ, we believe that we shall also live
with him."

This then explains the verse in question - verse 9.
The fact that Christ was resurrected from the dead, and ascended back to the Father in heaven never to die again, is the guarantee that he will return in like manner when the dead in Christ will be raised immortal, and those still alive at his coming will rise to meet them in the clouds, also with glorified bodies. Other parts of Paul's writings deal with that.
But for the verse in question, the surrounding verses give a straightforward explanation as to the two kinds of 'knowing' Paul speaks of. Some knew because they were eye-witnesses of Christ's resurrection and ascension, knowing he would return in glory in like manner. Others had never known that personally, but they believed the eye-witness testimony of those ones. Once they put faith in that good news (the gospel of salvation in Christ) they then knew experientially by the power of the Holy Spirit that it was so. They had exactly the same conviction as those eye-witnesses.
Then Paul builds on that in chapter 6 to show the consequences of knowing such things; how they are to eschew sin, to walk in newness of life, and expect to live with Christ to die no more, sin and death no longer enslaving them. Verse 9 is a theological knowing, based on Holy Spirit understanding of the consequences of Christ's bodily crucifixion, resurrection, ascension and future return.

Romans 6:6 is present tense (Strong's G1097 to know "absolutely", or to "understand"), so as to 'now live in that understanding', or to walk in that faith.
I see Romans 6:9 'knowing' as being past tense (per Strong's G1492), as in 'the actual understanding that occurred at the moment of belief'.
For more clarity, I believe Romans 6:9 is in reference to when the Spirit also seals the believers soul for eternity:
Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Ephesians 4:30

And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

In regard to 1 Corinthians 15:3, I do not see these believers as being those who literally saw the resurrected Christ.  Paul Himself did not physically see Christ prior to Christ's ascension into heaven.  It was from heaven that Christ ascended in glory gave Paul his gospel (Gal 1:11-12).  The purpose of Paul's gospel was to share his 'good news' with those who would not have physically seen Christ's death, burial and resurrection.  Paul's gospel is literally about believing the truth's found in these verses (1 Cor 15:1-4), "not by sight" (2 Cor 5:7), but by having faith alone in Christ alone (Eph 2:8-9).
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

Those in verse 2 who "believed" this gospel are those in verse 1 who also "received" (from Strong's G3880) the ministry of reconciliation (2 Cor 5:18).  They, with Paul being the administer (1 Tim 1:16, Eph 3:1-2), have been commissioned to spread this specific 'good news', just as all believers in it are commissioned to do.  Believers accept this appointment by belief in it.  Just as no one living in this age of God's grace, they did not necessarily see the events that transpired, but they believe that they did.

Is this related to What is the difference between οἴδασιν (in John 15:21) and γνόντες (in Romans 1:21)??

@Ray Butterworth Thanks. The question you mention does draw a line between sorts of knowing but does not mention how in Ro 6:9 people know "Christ being raised from the dead will never die again".
